# Cannot read property 'style' of null when use progress bar in drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I got this when i use progress bar in my drupal module . i searched a lot and the answer was this : **You are calling this script before DOM is ready**

part of script is :

```
var $w = window,
    $d = document,
    $circ = document.querySelector('.animated-circle'),
    $progCount = document.querySelector('.progress-count'),
    init,
    wh,
    h,
    sHeight;

function updateProgress(perc) {
    var circle_offset = 126 * perc;

    $circ.style.strokeDashoffset = 126 - circle_offset;

    $progCount.innerHTML = (Math.round(perc * 100) + "%");
}

init = function() {
    var events = ['resize', 'load'],
    top, perc, i, len;

    setSizes();

    $w.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    top = this.pageYOffset || $d.documentElement.scrollTop;
    perc = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, top / sHeight));
    updateProgress(perc);

    }, false);

    for (i = 0, len = events.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    $w.addEventListener(events[i], handler, false);
    }
};
```

I even add this to init function but nothing happened :

```
if($circ != null){
  updateProgress(perc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your entire script but its likely that it needs to go inside a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
}
```

or

```
$(function() {
    // your code
}
```

This is so the DOM is loaded when 'circ' is initialized.